# Is there yet a solution that affords collaboration with two users, two cursors, one monitor?

Tags: linux, xorg, multiple-users, multiseat, collaboration

I am looking for a solution that is similar in some ways to [multiseat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration), but with one important difference:

I want two (or perhaps n) users to be able to sit at the *same monitor*, sharing *the same desktop environment*, but be able to use their own keyboard and mouse, with their own cursor.

The basic use case is that I want my wife and I to be able to collaborate, mostly working on our own things, but occasionally directly collaborating.  I want to be able to say, "hey, do you think this is right?"  ...and for her to be able to jump over with her cursor, making corrections or copying-and-pasting.

Ideally, I want this to be a linux environment.

It seems that X11 provides for this possibility with a configuration called "Multi-pointer X," or "MPX."  [Here's the article about it on the X-wiki](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/MPX/).

However, I'm surprised to find that, apparently, this solution hasn't been implemented by any window managers, at least in a documented way.  Instead, they seem regard "the user" as owning all HIDs, and all working on a single cursor and focal point.

[Here's a SuperUser question that contains an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/367882/windows-manager-which-allows-multiple-active-windows-multiple-input-devices), but it is unsatisfying as it does not allow keyboard input to different window at the same time.

Since the architecture of GNU / Linux / X11 doesn't seem to *preclude* this configuration, so I'm surprised to see that it hasn't come of age, as it strikes me as of great use in a number of cases, personal and professional.

Or am I wrong and there's something right in front of me? :-)

Comment: +1 for a well-researched question, even if I personally fail to see how having windows from several users on the same screen could be productive. IMO you'll be constanty getting in each other's way when opening or resizing windows.

Comment: http://multicursor-wm.sourceforge.net/ *claims* to be able to do it, but with seperate clients.

Comment: If each user gets his/her own keyboard, how is keyboard focus supposed to be handled? AFAIK X allows only one focussed window, and even if you patched this somehow, FocusIn/FocusOut events for multiple windows are sure to confuse some progroms.

Comment: The only implementation I know is this one: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=u8qgehH3kEQ

Answer (score 2):

This does not work with bare Windows, but might be possible with third-party software.

[TeamPlayer](https://www.dicolab.com/products_teamplayer.html) (shareware, $49.95) is described as :

> It allows multiple users to simultaneously utilize the operating
>   system, applications and files.
>
> - Multiple cursors on screen with multiple attached mice/keyboards
> - Remote connecting users from anywhere using the free TeamCONNECT app
> - Cursor-colors and on-the-fly editable cursor labels
> - Area restrictions of cursors, confining them to any resizeable area on screen
> - Limited free LITE version available (for non commercial uses only)

TeamPlayer LITE is the free version, limited to a maximum of two users,
which seems to be the version you need.

<sub>Comment : I have no experience with this product.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Comment: Question says Ideally, I want this to be a linux environment.  Also, if you haven't tried it, *how do you know it even works?*?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Ideally!=absolutely. And don't look a gift(free) horse(software) in the mouth - just try it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: In addition, I think that an equivalent solution doesn't exist on Linux, where in multiseat a seat is defined as keyboard+monitor+mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a program called [GlovePIE](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AHpjca2uZSaDa9s&cid=3A491822FA9A0EF0&id=3A491822FA9A0EF0%21294&parId=3A491822FA9A0EF0%21270&action=locate) for Windows, and it is able to bind HID's to almost literally whatever you want.  They have a free example script that enables 2 mice to be used to control 2 different pointers on the screen.  One cursor acts as the real cursor, and the other one acts as a fake.  Anytime that the fake cursor needs to click, the real cursor and the fake cursor temporarily switch positions.

This program can definitely suit your needs of multitasking using one computer.  Some functions can even be created using its GUI, such as binding the 'a' key to the left arrow key.  However, to actually do what you are talking about would take some expertise in general coding, as implementing a multi-user configuration would not be something you could create inside of the GUI easily.  There is extensive help in the program itself, and this can be a feasible alternative for multiseat.

Comment: What does it work on? And it might be handy to talk about what it would involve to get this to work as the OP needs. Also... its on livedrive... isn't there a proper webpage?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions...  And yes, there is a proper webpage, and I should probably link to it, but the original download on the site is broken, as the site is quite old.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you still can't - not perfectly anyway. WM support is actually a pretty minor thing, tho having separate themes per cursor would be *nice*. Getting single session/multi seat is oddly trivial, with each keyboard and mouse paired, though you can't pick two different spots on a file and start typing at once -  I suspect this is a limitation of whatever software you run rather than the system. I got this running on ubuntu 16.10, though xinput2 should be supported on most modern linuxes.

Many of the *moving parts* you need exist - [multi pointer X](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X) is built into modern versions of X, though the *closest thing* to a working window manager hasn't been updated to *close to a decade* -and the documentation seems require x2x for some odd reason. You can *totally* get two cursors with their own keyboards working

Now, here's what works *perfectly*

I'm testing this with lubuntu - I've gotten *two* pointers (which look the same) with their own *keyboard* and *mouse* support.

You'll want to install xinput - apt has this.

xinput list gives you a list of devices. Now, you'd want to create a second (or third, or forth) set of pointers

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (13)]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard                        id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Create the second set of inputs with and add the two devices with

`xinput create-master pointer2`
`xinput reattach 10 "pointer2 pointer"`
`xinput reattach 17 "pointer2 keyboard"`

This attaches the SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad  and 
Chicony USB Keyboard  to the secondary inputs. I suspect you can use the names of the devices as well.

Now comes the part where I'm stuck - your *software* has to be aware that there's two cursors with seperate inputs - and I don't mean sublime text style. There's nothing out there, and it isn't really a window manager issue.

So yeah, you can get 90% of what you want, but not all the way. You can't *simultaniously* type, but you can move your cursors independantly, and 'hotseat' between your keyboards.

You'd also need to run these commands as needed, there's no documentation on X for this from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Why uncessasirly restrict yourselves to what can fit on the screen, when you can have a better experience with multiple screens, using a shared notepad such as [Etherpad](https://beta.etherpad.org/), [Piratepad](http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/newpad), or ten other similar programs here: http://alternativeto.net/software/piratepad/

Answer (score 0):

THere's another similar answer for this
  - [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc?rq=1)

the quick answer is NO.. multi user input has not yet been fully developed, due to the essential need for two parallel user accounts being shared simultaneously, an additional layer of processor priority control being lacking, and the general confusion which would surround a computer trying to determine WHO is in control....

It might seem like an innocuous thing.. However, imagine two pilots trying to fly a plane at the same time - - both pushing and pulling on the yoke... the plane wouldn't know fi it should go up or down.... not a good thing...

Comment: I don't think your analogy is compelling - a plane can fly in only one direction at a time, while the userland experience of a computer is that it does many things at the same time.  Also, as I pointed out in my question, most of the hard problems are already solved - X11 actually provides for multiple pointers from input.  It's just that most window managers don't have a UI to take advantage of it.  I'm hoping someone will chime in with one I haven't heard about.