# Will a new GTX 1050 GPU work with an old P5N-T board?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

My system has an old [P5N-T Deluxe](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5NT_Deluxe/) mainboard (NVIDIA 780i chipset), with PCI-Express 2.0 and a old GeForce 8800GT. I'm looking to upgrade the card, and was considering a new [GTX 1050 Ti](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1050/) (powered through the PCI-e). All new cards specs require PCI-Express 3.0, but my understanding is that is backward compatible to 2.0, so even if the mainboard bandwith cannot fill the GPU pipeline, at least it should work. Sometime in future I will have to change the MB/CPU/RAM as well eventually, and I'd rather keep then the GPU I buy now.

Is there anything else I should consider, is there some other reason why an old P5N-T will not work with a new generation GPU card?

Comment: Are you running at least Windows 7 or newer? If yes then the 1050 TI should have no trouble installing on the OS and running on that hardware. Heck, you could even go back to PCIe v1.0 and the card should still work. My note about having Windows 7 at minimum is important btw.

Comment: Yes, it is Windows 7

Comment: Perfect, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it'll work. For that matter, chances are the PCIe bus wouldn't be a bottleneck. Your new video card's going to draw power through the PCIe bus I think, which should be fine (The PCI spec insists video cards should be able to draw 75w).

In fact, between the 8000 series [tendancy to die early](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1028703/all-nvidia-g84-g86s-bad) (I'm impressed yours lasted that long) and that systems of that era, especially with sufficient ram and such [do benefit from relatively modern graphics cards](https://superuser.com/questions/1145348/is-there-yet-a-solution-that-affords-collaboration-with-two-users-two-cursors/1158113?noredirect=1#comment1670337_1158113), its actually a pretty good idea.